# Making sure a person redirects to login page

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble brainstorming a solution for this. If I need someone to redirect to the login page if they aren't logged in, how do I make sure they actually redirect? What if they keep the code from redirecting and they still have access to the page.
Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Can you do it on the server side? Then they can't prevent JS from running/redirecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ever **Don't trust frontend**.

The sole purpose of frontend is  To make smooth user experience .

### How to tackle your problem

suppose u r sending a message for 3 people (john , joseph , riya )

#### What you are doing

you have login.html & message.html

if john enters correct userName and password then send it to message.html and store some sever unique id of that person in browser storage(cookie,session,local).

if john does not have unique id then in js validate it and redirect to login.html

#### Problem with it

if some one stop the running of js then !!!!

one way to tackel is to add `noscript` html tag.
but some browser can by pass that also .

## What is auctual way to do it

empty the message.html by default .

in js use fetch , axios or jquery ... to ask for messages to server with the unique token of requested person.

### server work

1. check if the unique  id is valid.
2. check what message is for that unique id .

e.g

```
| name     | token          | message |
| -------- | -------------- | ------- |
| john     | 1              |b        |
| joseph   | 2              |a        |
| riya     | 3              |b        |
```

for token 2 message is a
for token 1  and token 3 message is b

for token 4 no id .

in frontend if the the id is invalid send to login page

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use the server for this. If your server sends a `location` header. It will redirect the user without him being able to do anything about it.
Example in PHP: `header("location:index.php");`

If this is not possible you can do it on the client (javascript), but you are not guaranteed, they will not disable javascript or just intercept and stop this part of the code working.

---

However you do it, you must be sure that even if a user tries to access any of your admin endpoints, they must prove that they are logged in. Otherwise, someone will just try `example.com/admin/privateData.json` and might get it...